# wordpress remove views from action links in a custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, plugin-development, filters

I have created a custom post type, but I want to remove the View link from actions, in the listing of the custom post.

I have tried this snippet

```
   add_filter( 'post_row_actions',array(&$this, 'remove_row_actions', 10, 1));
   public function remove_row_actions($action){
       unset($action['view']);
       return $action;
   }
```

But it throws

> `call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members in D:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 173`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got typo in your add_filter. Try this:

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions',array(&$this, 'remove_row_actions'), 10, 1);

public function remove_row_actions($action){
    unset($action['view']);
    return $action;
}
```

Comment: doesnt work still, i renamed post_row_actions to page_row_actions also, still it doesnt get removed

Comment: Must be something with your class code. Inserting this code into functions.php works great: add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions', 10, 1);

function remove_row_actions($action){
    unset($action['view']);
    return $action;
}

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `class` methods and functions is that you don't throw in an `array()` when calling the function and ommit the leading `public/protected/private/static` string in front of `function`. Also don't use the `&` when calling `$this` (which is the current class object), as it's PHP4 syntax for passing the class as reference. PHP5 doesn't need this. The third note is, that you use the `array()` in the way `array( __CLASS__, 'method_name' )`. The priority `10` and the number of arguments `1` as *separate* arguments and don't belong *inside* the array.

```
   add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'wpse90843_remove_row_actions' );
   public function wpse90843_remove_row_actions( $action )
   {
       unset $action['view'];
       return $action;
   }
```

**Last note:** Don't just grab a snippet from somewhere if you don't understand what you're doing. Get someone who can read this for you. Stuff like this can seriously mess up your installation.

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers address that the OP asks how to do this for a custom post type. Unsetting `$action['view']` will remove it for all posts, pages and custom post types if you don't get more specific.

Here's what I came up with. (Replace "mycustomtheme" with your theme or plugin slug, replace "myposttype" with your custom post type slug.)

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'mycustomtheme_remove_myposttype_row_actions' );
function mycustomtheme_remove_myposttype_row_actions( $action )
{
    if ('myposttype' == get_post_type()) {
        unset($action['view']);
    }
    return $action;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to remove the 'public' if it is not in a class.

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'wpse90843_remove_row_actions' );
function wpse90843_remove_row_actions( $action )
{
    unset($action['view']);
    return $action;
}
```